# How to rotate a set of points on z = 0 plane in 3-D, preserving pairwise distances?

Tags: java, rotation, matrix

I have a set of points `double n[]` on the plane `z = 0`.
And I have another set of points `double[] m` on the plane `ax + by + cz + d = 0`.
Length of `n` is equal to length of `m`.
Also, euclidean distance between `n[i]` and `n[j]` is equal to euclidean distance between `m[i]` and `m[j]`.

I want to rotate `n[]` in 3-D, such that for all `i`, `n[i] = m[i]` would be true.

In other words, I want to turn a plane into another plane, preserving the pairwise distances.

Here's my code in java. But it does not help so much:

```
double[] rotate(double[] point, double[] currentEquation, double[] targetEquation)
{

    double[] currentNormal = new double[]{currentEquation[0], currentEquation[1], currentEquation[2]};
    double[] targetNormal = new double[]{targetEquation[0], targetEquation[1], targetEquation[2]};
    targetNormal = normalize(targetNormal);
    double angle = angleBetween(currentNormal, targetNormal);
    double[] axis = cross(targetNormal, currentNormal);
    double[][] R = getRotationMatrix(axis, angle);
    return rotated; 
}

double[][] getRotationMatrix(double[] axis, double angle)
{
    axis = normalize(axis);

    double cA = (float)Math.cos(angle);
    double sA = (float)Math.sin(angle);
    Matrix I = Matrix.identity(3, 3);
    Matrix a = new Matrix(axis, 3);


    Matrix aT = a.transpose();

    Matrix a2 = a.times(aT);

    double[][] B = 
        {
            {0, axis[2], -1*axis[1]},
            {-1*axis[2], 0, axis[0]},
            {axis[1], -1*axis[0], 0}
        };
    Matrix A = new Matrix(B);

    Matrix R = I.minus(a2);


    R = R.times(cA);
    R = R.plus(a2);
    R = R.plus(A.times(sA));
    return R.getArray();
}
```

This is what I get. The point set on the right side is actually part of a point set on the left side. But they are on another plane.

Here's a 2-D representation of what I try to do:

[image]
There are two lines. The line on the bottom is the line I have. The line on the top is the target line. The distances are preserved (a, b and c). 
[image]

**Edit:**
I have tried both methods written in answers. They both fail (I guess).

Method of *Martijn Courteaux*

```
   public static double[][] getRotationMatrix(double[] v0, double[] v1, double[] v2, double[] u0, double[] u1, double[] u2)
        {

            RealMatrix M1 = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(new double[][]{
                    {1,0,0,-1*v0[0]},
                    {0,1,0,-1*v0[1]},
                    {0,0,1,0},
                    {0,0,0,1}
            });

            RealMatrix M2 = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(new double[][]{
                    {1,0,0,-1*u0[0]},
                    {0,1,0,-1*u0[1]},
                    {0,0,1,-1*u0[2]},
                    {0,0,0,1}
            });

            Vector3D imX = new Vector3D((v0[1] - v1[1])*(u2[0] - u0[0]) - (v0[1] - v2[1])*(u1[0] - u0[0]), 
                    (v0[1] - v1[1])*(u2[1] - u0[1]) - (v0[1] - v2[1])*(u1[1] - u0[1]),
                    (v0[1] - v1[1])*(u2[2] - u0[2]) - (v0[1] - v2[1])*(u1[2] - u0[2])
            ).scalarMultiply(1/((v0[0]*v1[1])-(v0[0]*v2[1])-(v1[0]*v0[1])+(v1[0]*v2[1])+(v2[0]*v0[1])-(v2[0]*v1[1])));

            Vector3D imZ = new Vector3D(findEquation(u0, u1, u2));
            Vector3D imY = Vector3D.crossProduct(imZ, imX);

            double[] imXn = imX.normalize().toArray();
            double[] imYn = imY.normalize().toArray();
            double[] imZn = imZ.normalize().toArray();
            RealMatrix M = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(new double[][]{
                    {imXn[0], imXn[1], imXn[2], 0},
                    {imYn[0], imYn[1], imYn[2], 0},
                    {imZn[0], imZn[1], imZn[2], 0},
                    {0, 0, 0, 1}
            });
            RealMatrix rotationMatrix = MatrixUtils.inverse(M2).multiply(M).multiply(M1);
            return rotationMatrix.getData(); 
        }
```

[image]

Method of *Sam Hocevar*

```
static double[][] makeMatrix(double[] p1, double[] p2, double[] p3)
    {
        double[] v1 = normalize(difference(p2,p1));
        double[] v2 = normalize(cross(difference(p3,p1), difference(p2,p1)));
        double[] v3 = cross(v1, v2);
        double[][] M = { { v1[0], v2[0], v3[0], p1[0] },
                         { v1[1], v2[1], v3[1], p1[1] },
                         { v1[2], v2[2], v3[2], p1[2] },
                         {   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   1.0 } };
        return M;
    }

    static double[][] createTransform(double[] A, double[] B, double[] C,
                         double[] P, double[] Q, double[] R)
    {
        RealMatrix c = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(makeMatrix(A,B,C));
        RealMatrix t = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(makeMatrix(P,Q,R));
        return MatrixUtils.inverse(c).multiply(t).getData();
    }
```

[image]

The blue points are the calculated points. The black lines indicate the offset from the real position.

Comment: If your goal is that `m[i] = n[i]` for all `i`, well then copy the array, given that the lengths are equal as well.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you are trying. You actually don't have the target points. Well, then the best way to do this is to use coordinate transformation. Tomorrow I'm having an exam. If no one answered until then, I will try to formulate an answer. Basically the trick is to create a matrix that converts from one basis to another. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux I need the transformation/rotation matrix as well.

Comment: Can you maybe rewrite the question to say precisely what data you *know* and what you *don’t*? Right now it looks like you know `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, but it seems that you actually don’t? Also in your 2D representation, the *b* distance isn’t actually preserved, is that an error?

Comment: @SamHocevar I know `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` but there are infinitely many numbers of transformations of points from `z=0` to `ax+by+cz+d=0`. I know three points on second plane as well. That reduces the last degree of freedom.

Comment: @cagirici okay, if you know three points in the target plane, then the problem becomes easy and you don’t even need `a b c d`. I posted new code in my answer.

Comment: @cagirici: For Sam's method, try `t.multiply(MatrixUtils.inverse(c))` instead. And what are the black lines exactly?

Comment: Now, the coordinates are more reasonable. But still, I think I need to reflect the points. [see image here](http://imgur.com/Rz5ikW2) [same image from a different angle](http://imgur.com/qHf5F9z)

Comment: And for my method, it looks like you translated `imX` wrong into your code. For example: `(-y3+y1)` should be `(-v2[1]+v0[1])`. I can't seem to find that piece in your code.

Comment: And what is in the `findEquation` method?

Comment: Also, the original points, which are the red ones, I suppose are **not** in the z=0 plane. That totally breaks my method.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Hold on, I'll upload more precise images. They are not the original points.

Comment: I've written `(-y3+y1)` as `(y1-y3)`. Thought they both are the same. [here](http://imgur.com/OjCgM2X), black lines indicate the offset of the points calculated. red lines indicate the offset between the coordinates on `z=0` plane and the original coordinates. blue points are the calculated points. red points are the coordinates on `z=0` plane. The meeting point of a red line and black line is the location that the blue point should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New post, clean and well. I tried to implement Sam's answer, but slightly different, and it works. This approach is simpler than all the others, simply because it relies on you to make sure that your preserve the distance. If you don't, it will still match the points, but without distance and angles being preserved.

[image]

Here you have the check:

[image]

In code this would be (based on Sam's snippet):

```
static double[][] makeMatrix(double[] p1, double[] p2, double[] p3)
{
    double[] v1 = difference(p2,p1);
    double[] v2 = difference(p3,p1);
    double[] v3 = cross(v1, v2);
    double[][] M = { { v1[0], v2[0], v3[0], p1[0] },
                     { v1[1], v2[1], v3[1], p1[1] },
                     { v1[2], v2[2], v3[2], p1[2] },
                     {   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   1.0 } };
    return M;
}

static double[][] createTransform(double[] A, double[] B, double[] C,
                     double[] P, double[] Q, double[] R)
{
    RealMatrix c = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(makeMatrix(A,B,C));
    RealMatrix t = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(makeMatrix(P,Q,R));
    return t.multiply(MatrixUtils.inverse(c)).getData();
}

static double[][] transformPoints(double[][] points, double[][] matrix)
{
    double[][] tfd = new double[points.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; ++i)
    {
        tfd[i] = multiply(matrix, points[i]);
    }
    return tfd;
}

static double[] multiply(double[][] matrix, double[] point)
{
     double[] temp = new double[4];
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) temp[i] = point[i];
     temp[3] = 1.0;

     double[] res = new double[3];
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
         {
             res[i] += temp[j] * matrix[i][j];
         }
     }

     return res;
}
```

Comment: That code did the trick. Last modification I did is to shift the points on `z=0` to positive side of the plane (both x and y coordinates are greater than zero).

Comment: I think [those](http://imgur.com/mvBxXWa) errors are not because of the method.

Comment: But again: what are those black lines?

Comment: Those black lines are where the points should be. Blue points are where they are calculated.

Comment: And how do you know where they should be? You're trying to find their position?

Comment: That's right. I find their position on `z=0`. Afterwards, I take three of the points and their `XY` coordinates. Those are `A`, `B` and `C`. Then I take their actual coordinates; `P`, `Q`, `R`. Then I do the operations.

Comment: But the blue points are calculated and the black lines indicate that they are not at the right position. How do you know what their position should be? Do you have a list of data that says where it should be? If so, that data set is most likely wrong, since this is a linear operation and cannot fail in particular cases, if it works for many others.

Comment: I have the 3-D coordinates and 2-D coordinates of all points. Some of them are given and some of them are to be calculated. Which means, some of the blue points are given and *some* of the points who are coplanar to them are to be calculated. Their coordinates are stored, but hidden.

Comment: Well, then I guess that your data you have is wrong. Is there a way you can verify that data?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you have three points `A`, `B`, `C`, and three points `P`, `Q`, `R` and you would like to know the affine transform (*i.e.* preserving distances) that transforms the first set into the second set.

Finding the transform is straightforward; you just need to create two orthonormal bases from your sets of points, fill matrixes with the basis vectors, and combine them.

Here is one way to do it (assuming you got some method to subtract two vectors):

```
double[][] makeMatrix(double[] p1, double[] p2, double[] p3)
{
    double[] v1 = normalize(p2 - p1);
    double[] v2 = normalize(cross(p3 - p1, v1));
    double[] v3 = cross(v1, v2);
    double[][] M = { { v1[0], v2[0], v3[0], p1[0] },
                     { v1[1], v2[1], v3[1], p1[1] },
                     { v1[2], v2[2], v3[2], p1[2] },
                     {   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   1.0 } };
    return M;
}

mat4 createTransform(double[] A, double[] B, double[] C,
                     double[] P, double[] Q, double[] R)
{
    return mul(inverse(makeMatrix(A, B, C)),
               makeMatrix(P, Q, R));
}
```

Comment: `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are the components of target plane, right?

Comment: Yes, they’re from your question: “I have another set of points `double[] m` on the plane `ax + by + cz + d = 0`”.

Comment: Look at his requirements. He says he has 3 points on the original plane, and 3 points on the target plane. The transformation matrix should match these 3 points. By only fixing the plane, there is the degree of freedom I talked about in my old answer (still online) and the comments.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux But the question doesn’t mention these three points, and they appear nowhere in the code… The question is “I want to turn a plane into another plane, preserving the pairwise distances”.

Comment: Yes, I know. It's a bit vague. But I explained it first by just rotating it correctly, but he wanted to get rid of the degree of freedom.

Comment: This seems so easy... And looks correct as well. Genius. How come I didn't think of this approach? +1

Comment: I hope my method produces the same matrix... Damn I'm feeling dumb right now.

Comment: I'm wondering if you didn't switch the order of the multiplication. I think it should be: M1^(-1)*M2.

Comment: I will try this one just after I finish Mr. Courteaux's.

Comment: Both methods are the same, but producing coordinates too big. Planes look like they are reflected through an imaginary axis.

Comment: @cagirici This is usually caused by a) mismatched matrix multiplication order, b) mismatched matrix layout. Since you don’t use a fully standard API, it might require tweaking. Try to transpose `M` in `makeMatrix()`, **or** try to swap the arguments to `mul()`, **or** try to do both.

Comment: [in this image](http://imgur.com/Qt3tYca), black points are actual coordinates. Red points are coordinates on `z=0` and blue points are calculated points.

Comment: @SamHocevar I triead what you've suggested and I get [this](http://imgur.com/hmlJm9N). Two planes are rotated perfectly but shifted wrongly. The third plane is too far away (at coordinates 2000, 3000 etc. even though my space is 100 by 100 by 100)

Comment: @cagirici: You probably did not add a 1 to your 3-Vectors, but a 0. Always add 1 to your coordinates when you use matrices. There is a perfect explanation for why this is 1 and how it works, but that would lead us too far. That involves understanding the difference between linear spaces and affine spaces.

Comment: @cagirici Could you maybe [paste](http://pastebin.com/) sample values for `A B C P Q R`, for the two intermediate matrices, and for the final matrix? This could help reproduce results and find the problem.

Answer (score 3):

## **Update:**

This was much harder to solve than I thought. However, I think I managed it to fix it, after trying 5 different approaches. So, the requirements really are that you have 3 source points and 3 corresponding destination points. And that you are sure that the distance between the points is conserved. And finally that the source points define a plane.

**(Note that all indices in Maple start at 1 instead of 0)**

Your 3 source and destination points are represented like this:

[image: Source and Dest points]

First step is to create matrices that translate these points to the origin. The matrixes will be:

[image: Translate Matrices]

Here `M1` will put the source points to the origin and `M2` will do the same for the dest points, both using the first of the three points. Now we have two times a zero vector and two source vectors and two dest vectors:

[image: Centered vectors]

The names refer to Source Points Centered (spC) and Destination Points Centered (dpC).

Next, we are going to find the linear combination of those two source vectors that produce the unit x vector (1, 0, 0). So we are looking for a solution for:

```
alpha * spC[0] + beta * spC[1] = (1, 0, 0)
```

Maple can solve this for us:

[image: Solve lin comb]

So, now, we have found a representation for the unit vector in function of the source vectors. We know that after applying the final linear transformation, the image of the x unit vector will be a linear combination of the destination vectors, again with the same coefficients we just found: alpha and beta. So, let's compute the image of the x unit vector after our linear transform:

[image: Image of X unit]

So, at this point, we already know what the image of the x unit vector will be. We can also compute the normal vector of our three destination points. This will be the image of our z unit vector. This normal vector is given by the cross product of the two destination vectors.

[image: Image of Z unit]

So, now we know already two images of the unit vectors x and z. The image of the unit vector y can be found by taking into account that we want an orthonormal transformation. Just take the crossproduct of these two image vectors, to get the image of the y unit vector. Once we found the images, we have to normalize them of course by dividing by their length:

[image: Images and normalize]

(Note: the requirement was that the distance was conserved. That means that normalizing the image of x would not be necessary.)

Now we can create the linear component of our transformation matrix by putting `imXn`, `imYn` and `imZn` in that order as column in a matrix:

[image: Matrix]

You can see I homogenized the matrix to an affine matrix by adding zeroes at the right and bottom and a 1 at right bottom position of the matrix. To clarify:

```
a b c              a b c 0
d e f    becomes   d e f 0
g h i              g h i 0
                   0 0 0 1
```

Now we can compute the total matrix! The transformation is basically:

1. Translate the source points to the origin
2. Apply the linear transform
3. Translate the points to the dest position

This gives this matrix in total:

[image: Total matrix]

---

## Old answer:

Well, this was actually a great exercise for my finals tomorrow. Here you have the technical part. If you want to, I can add explanation later:

[Large image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j2Pq.png)

[image]

This is done with Maple. So as you can see, if we let the normal vector of plane `z = 0`, which is `<0, 0, 1>` get through the transformation matrix, we have the expected normal vector for your `ax + by + cz + d = 0` plane. If you assume that `a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1`, then it's even nicer.

Note that you have one degree of freedom: randomVector can be random and determines the rotation, because you didn't specify anything on how to rotate this thing.

If you make the randomVector less random, you can get a cleaner matrix, but I'm not sure if this will work for all kinds of target planes, because it can occur that the CrossProduct turns out to be zero, if the normalVector and the randomVector can be parallel:

[Large image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO3i4.png)
[image]

Also note that you might want to add a translational component afterwards to make the plane match the equation `ax + by + cz + d = 0`, because if you transform all your points with this matrix, they are going to be in the plane `ax + by + cz = 0` right now.

Comment: May the force be with you in your exams, my noble friend. But there is no randomness. Why would you suggest that?

Comment: You can rotate all the points in the target plane around it's normal vector, and they will still be in the same plane. That is your degree of freedom.

Comment: What if the orientation is the same? I mean, when you rotate the initial plane, it is parallel to the target plane?

Comment: No of course they are not parallel anymore. Parallel planes have the same normal vector. So a parallel plane to z=0 would be z=d. You really need to find a way to specify how you are going get rid of your degree of freedom. Think about it. If you find something, I will be glad to do the calculations in Maple for you :)

Comment: Yes, I see what you are trying. But this preservers distance. Every rotation preserves distance. Another way to clarify your degree of freedom is to see that, before you rotate your plane into space, that you rotate all your points in z=0 around the z axis, so your points are still in z=0, but rotate around the origin.

Comment: OK. Now, I see what you say. I know the coordinates of three points from second plane. Say `m[0]`, `m[1]`, `m[2]`. That reduces the degree of freedom, I think.

Comment: Yes that does reduce the degree of freedom. I will update my answer soon, maybe tomorrow.

Comment: Is it OK I just start writing from imageOfXUnit?

Comment: Yes that is fine. But will need the translation matrices M1 and M2. However, your code will be a bit shorter if you define alpha and beta. And use those as coefficients for those two vectors.

Comment: Can I ask, what is `norm(v, 2)`? I only have `getNorm()`, `getNorm1()`, `getNormInf()` and `getNormSq()` functions available. Is it `norm1`?

Comment: You are looking for getNorm(). It is the Maple notation for the 2-Norm. Which is basically the euclidian distance. The function `getNormInf()` will return the maximum of the components and `getNorm1()` will return the sum of the absolute values of the components, also known as the taxicab-metric. More info about different norms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm

Comment: I'm at last step. What is `M2^(-1).Mext.M1`? Is it dot product? After this step, I will multiply the matrix with the point and report the results.

Comment: It are matrix multiplications. So you have to invert matrix `M2` and multiply them in that order with `Mext` and `M1`. Inverting `M2` can be done easily by negating the translational components of this matrix which are at the most left column, but leave the one at the bottom in tact.

Comment: Is it normal that I get a 4-Vector at the end?

Comment: Yes, perfectly normal. The fourth component should be 1 and you can ignore that component. Just use the first three, they represent x, y and z.

Comment: But I need 4th coordinate to multiply a vector by a 4-by-4 matrix. Is that 0 or 1?

Comment: You have to extend your given points with a 1 as fourth component.